# A MERGE statement must be terminated by a semi-colon (;)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm using this code, but I get the error message above.Why this?
I also created linked server to a second PC with linked name = 192.168.1.101 also username=xxxx and password=xxxx

```
WITH Source AS 
  ( SELECT id, name FROM Tamio.dbo.memberform WHERE active = 1 or active =0) 
MERGE INTO [192.168.1.101].Imatismos.dbo.customermaster AS target 
  USING Source ON target.id = source.id 
  WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET target.name = source.name 
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (id, name) VALUES (source.id, source.name)
```

Comment: You can't use Merge when the Target table is a remote table. Not sure if this limitation has been lifted in Sql Server 2014/2016 but as far as Sql Server 2012 this is documented in MSDN. At this point I suggest to discard the Merge approach and use a Stored Procedure with separate steps to perform your UPDATE or INSERT

Comment: Is there any other way which i can succeed this?

Comment: Is it right way to transfer all my table to another PC-B(Remote) Table and then merge from my two tables into PC-B?

Comment: Seriously? What part of the error message was unclear?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One way is to copy all your source data into a [staging table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1437794-391-1.aspx) and process it afterwards:

1) Copy the data

```
INSERT INTO Imatismos.stg.memberform
SELECT id, name
FROM Tamio.dbo.memberform WHERE active = 1 or active = 0
```

2) The actual merge can be done locally (this is run on [192.168.1.101].Imatismos)

```
WITH Source AS 
  ( SELECT id, name FROM stg.memberform) 
MERGE INTO dbo.customermaster AS target 
  USING Source ON target.id = source.id 
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET target.name = source.name 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (id, name) VALUES (source.id, source.name);
```

Generally speaking, try to avoid running queries that "JOIN" over multiple servers, as this can lead to very poor performance.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question asked. If the OP has a follow up question they should ask a new question.

Answer (score 5):

add a semi-colon at the end of your Merge statement!

```
WITH Source AS 
  ( SELECT id, name FROM Tamio.dbo.memberform WHERE active = 1 or active =0) 
MERGE INTO [192.168.1.101].Imatismos.dbo.customermaster AS target 
  USING Source ON target.id = source.id 
  WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET target.name = source.name 
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (id, name) VALUES (source.id, source.name);
```

Comment: Now i get this message: The target of a MERGE statement cannot be a remote table, a remote view, or a view over remote tables.

Comment: read the docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb510625.aspx -> *target_table cannot be a remote table.*

Comment: @user6453809 that's a different question, asking a question on SO doesn't create some sort of helpdesk where people will work through all your related questions.